# All font awesome icons showing up except for one

Tags: fonts, font-awesome, webfonts

Facebook, Twitter, and Youtube icons all show up, but I cannot get the TripAdvisor icon to show up. I've double and triple checked that all html and css is identical for all icons. Why won't Trip Advisor show up? 
See this link. The icons are inthe top right of the header. http://keystonechamber.r.bookdirect.net/

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you are using font-awesome 4.4 or higher. Tripadvisor icon was introduced with 4.4 version of the icon library.

Comment: Thank you! I am using 4.2. I bet that's why.